# If I have N children, what percentage of my chromosomes will be passed on?

Tags: statistics

If I have one child half my chromosomes are passed on.
If I have two children somewhere between half and all my chromosomes will be passed on.
From a statistical perspective what is the average number of chromosomes inherited with N children? N<10

Comment: Do you mean the ratio of chromosomes you will likely share with any of your children , assuming a random half part is shared with each child ?

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any biological details, and taking the math question at face value, this is a fairly standard problem. The trick is to think about the probability that a chromosome is *not* passed on to any of the children.

As you state, if you have $M$ chromosomes and $1$ child, the probability that any given chromosome is passed on is $1/2$, and the expected value of the total number passed on is $M/2$. Of course, for just one child this expected value is also known to be the exact count. The other trivial case is no children, where the probability that a chromosome is passed on is $0$ and the expected value for the total is also $0$.

If you have $2$ children the probability that a given chromosome is passed on to *neither* child is $1/4$. Therefore, the probability that a given chromosome is inherited by *at least one* child is $3/4$ and the expected value for the total is simply $3M/4$.

This pattern continues for $3$ children where the probability that a chromosome is not inherited by any of them is $1/8$ and the expected value is $7M/8$. It should by now hopefully be clear that your question on the "average number of chromosomes inherited with N children" can be expressed simply as

$$
E = M\left(1-\frac 1 {2^N}\right)
$$

Note that even if the question is presented slightly differently, where there are pairs of chromosomes and each child gets one from each pair at random, the expected value is actually the same. This interesting result is because the probability that a given chromosome from each pair is *not* inherited by a given child is still $1/2$, and none of the math above changes.

Real biology may be different.

Comment: Real biology is not very different in terms of expectation, but is different in the sense that most of a child's chromosomes are a result of [chromosomal crossover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromosomal_crossover), so a child does not have pairs of chromosomes with one from each parent but instead pairs which mix those two chromosomes from the parents.